# Monospace font with exactly 15px height and 7px width

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, font-size

I'm using the font consolas and I want it to have 15 pixels height and 7 pixels width in all characters (monospace) with 100% precision (the characters don't have to stretch in visual but it's box limit has to have no decimals). I have been messing around with the CSS `font-size` property but the numbers are so random. Here's an example:

```js
function Update(){
  document.getElementById('Size').style.fontSize = document.getElementById('Input').value + "px";
  document.getElementById('Width').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Size').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  document.getElementById('Height').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Size').getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
Update()
```

```css
span {
  font-family: consolas;
}
```

```html
<span id="Size">1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</span>
<br>
<br>
<span>Font size: </span><input id="Input" oninput="Update()" value="12.7399992942810049711965802998747676610946655273437">
<br>
<span>Width (100 characters): </span><span id="Width"></span>
<br>
<span>Height (1 character): </span><span id="Height"></span>
```

You can change the size on that input and check if it goes under 700 (7px + 100characters). It's so random that I don't get it. Also, I just noticed that that's the limit, if you add a 5 in the end, it gets a width of 700.4375 but if you add a 4 you can add all the 9s in the world that it doesn't matter (probably float limit stuff).

Haven't tested with more precision (more than 100 characters) but what I want is to have a simple monospace font with 15x7 size so that I don't ever have to worry about weird size issues anymore.

**Edit with solution (after accepted answer):**

Working values for `<span>` with max 3000 characters width and/or height.

```js
for(var i=0;i<3000;i++){ // 3000
  document.getElementById('Size').innerHTML += "1"; // "1<br>" for some reason here in the Code Snippet the height is 53997 instead of 45000
}
function Update(){
  document.getElementById('Size').style.fontSize = document.getElementById('Input').value + "px";
  document.getElementById('Width').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Size').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  document.getElementById('Height').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Size').getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
Update()
```

```css
span {
  font-family: consolas;
  letter-spacing: 0.001192px; // 0.001192 to 0.001196
}
```

```html
<span id="Size"></span><br>
<input id="Input" oninput="Update()" value="12.739"> <span id="Width"></span><span>x</span><span id="Height"></span>
```

Comment: You will need `line-height: 1` for height I guess..

Comment: line-height: 1 won't work at all, you need to provide a unit for line-height. Either 100% or an absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to do it with CSS `letter-spacing: 0.001px;` property:

```js
function Update(){
  document.getElementById('Size').style.fontSize = document.getElementById('Input').value + "px";
  document.getElementById('Width').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Size').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  document.getElementById('Height').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Size').getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
Update()
```

```css
span {
  font-family: consolas;
  letter-spacing: 0.001px;
}
```

```html
<span id="Size">1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</span>
<br>
<br>
<span>Font size: </span><input id="Input" oninput="Update()" value="12.7399992942810049711965802998747676610946655273437">
<br>
<span>Width (100 characters): </span><span id="Width"></span>
<br>
<span>Height (1 character): </span><span id="Height"></span>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna test it out in all ways I can to make sure it works perfectly.

Comment: If I do add more characters to be more precise it does eventually gets back to the random numbers but I guess I just have to mess with the `letter-spacing`'s value too if I want it to be that perfect. Anyway, thanks for the answer, it's good enough! I'm trying to build a text editor by the way. :)

Comment: Glad I could help :). Good luck with the text editor building ;).